# Asp.net WebAPI - force use of HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, https

I am building an Asp.Net / WebAPI app, how can I ensure that this always is via https?

I am just using a standard web-hosting package at the moment so dont think I will be able to change anything on the IIS config as far as i am aware..

Answer (score -1):

The transport protocol has nothing to do with ASP.NET, it is a part of the web server, in your case IIS. If you don't have access to the IIS configuration, you can not ensure the use of HTTPS. Check with your hosting provider to make this change.